# Blend mode on svg image

Tags: css, svg

Why blend mode works on a normal image (img tag) but not inside an svg (image tag)?
Look at the example below to understand what I'm trying to achieve (I also want to keep the background clipped like the first image):

```css
.image-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    background: #70C053;
}

.image-wrapper image {
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
   filter: grayscale(100%);
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
 <div class="image-wrapper">
                <svg viewBox="0 0 250 250" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <defs>
                        <clipPath id="user-space" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                            <path fill="#FF0066"
                                d="M49.5,-65.4C58.2,-51.8,55.1,-30.5,54.2,-12.9C53.4,4.7,54.7,18.5,49.1,28.6C43.6,38.6,31.1,44.8,17.6,50.9C4.1,57,-10.5,62.8,-22.5,59.5C-34.5,56.1,-44.1,43.5,-53.7,29.7C-63.3,15.8,-73,0.6,-73.4,-15.7C-73.8,-32,-65,-49.4,-51.2,-62.2C-37.4,-75,-18.7,-83.1,0.9,-84.1C20.4,-85.2,40.9,-79.1,49.5,-65.4Z"
                                transform="translate(100 100)"></path>
                        </clipPath>
                    </defs>
                    <image width="100%" height="auto" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" xlink:href="https://source.unsplash.com/random"
                        clip-path="url(#user-space)"/>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="image-wrapper">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
            </div>
```

Comment: I would blend the SVG itself : `.image-wrapper svg {
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}`

Comment: Thanks that works! But I would really like to keep the color in the clip path

Comment: Works as expected in Chrome (though you have to remove `height="auto"`). What do you mean by "I would really like to keep the color in the clip path"?

Comment: The color should be applied only in the clip path area, the outside should remain white

Comment: Where would that white come from? You have a white rect with a mask that you don't show? If you just want to recolor the clipped-in part, why not use a filter instead of mix-blend-mode?

Comment: No I mean like using ` image { background: green; }` while having `background-blend-mode`, so the color will remain only in the clipped area

Comment: But currently you've set the background on `.image-wrapper`, so the whole div's rect will be green. If you want only the clipped area to be colored, you need to clip the part with the green background too. But once again, if you just want to colorize your clipped image, use a colorMatrix filter.

Comment: Many CSS properties do not apply to SVG sub-elements. You may have to apply that blend to the entire SVG.

Comment: Right I've used a feColorMatrix and now it works thanks

Answer (score -1):

The MDN docs have an example.

See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode#using_mix-blend-mode_with_svg